# Перенос сайта с http на https

Tags: ssl, http, https, .htaccess

Здравствуйте!

Получил SSL сертификат. Теперь необходимо поменять протокол с http на https, вследствие чего возникли некоторые трудности:

1. Что прописать в htaccess чтобы, сделать редирект с (http://www.site.ru, https://www.site.ru и http://site.ru) на https://site.ru (с регулярками туго у меня)?
2. К сайту подключается пара скриптов, к которым есть доступ только по http протоколу. Как быть? Можно ли как-то безболезненно прикрепить к https сайту скрипты по http?
3. Есть ли минусы или какие проблемы при переходе на https?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10489895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хостер прислал вот такой вариант, и все заработало:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но теперь появилась другая проблема...
Прежде чем сделать редирект с https://www.site.ru -> https://site.ru проверяется сертификат, а так как сертификат выдан для домена без WWW, выдается ошибка...

Comment: Как выяснилось, в данном случае ничего поделать нельзя, так как сертификат не  поддерживает поддомены. Думаю, что на первый год на это можно закрыть глаза. Проект новый, вряд ли найдутся пользователи, которые будут в адресной строке вводить https://www.site.ru. Скорее всего они просто напишут: www.site.ru, а отсюда их уже перекинет на https://site.ru

Answer (score 2):

Со StackOverflow:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Кроме того, можно делать перенаправление по номеру порта, например:

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Это перенаправит на HTTPS все запросы, полученные по 80 порту.

Вставлять HTTP скрипты на HTTPS сайт нельзя, это рушит всю безопасность, которой хотели добиться. Вы же для этого на HTTPS переходите?

Минусы или плюсы перехода зависят непосредственно от вашего проекта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только вот ни первый, ни второй код не помогли. Возникает циклическая переадрисация.

Comment: У вас https стоит на 80 порту? Второй вариант основан именно на адресе порта для https, https обычно на 443 порту.

В первом варианте посмотрите, как правильно добавить RewriteLog, а затем посмотрите, что там не так.

Возможно, ошибка вовсе не в этих строках, а в предыдущих или дальнейших инструкциях htaccess.

Comment: Я нашел вот такой кусок кода: 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Но он тоже вызывал циклическую переадресацию. Я тогда сделал запрос у хостера, он мне %{HTTPS} off заменил на %{HTTP_X_HTTPS} off. Циклов больше нет... Осталось только добиться того, чтобы с http://site.ru редиректил на https://site.ru.  Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Кстати, https стоит на 443 порту.   
А из файла .htaccess при тестировании, убирал все, что связанно с переадресацией. Так как тоже думал, что может быть дело не в этом коде, а в том, который идет после. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

на ВОРДПРЕСС помогло

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Nginx - лучше воспользоватся директивой **return код_состояния url**. Перенаправление лучше выполнять на уровне **location**, чтобы файлы **robots.txt и sitemap.xml** остались доступными для поисковых систем.
Контекст с http:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name domain.tld;
  server_name www.domain.tld;

  location ^/robots.txt {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ^/sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
  }
}
```

В рамках контекста http желательно включить компрессию:

```
gzip on;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss     text/javascript;
gzip_disable "msie6";
```

---

Вам также может помочь статья [Nginx. Переход с http на https](https://www.influunt.ru/nginx-switch-from-http-to-https).