# .htaccess как сдлать редирект на страницу index.php с http на https?

Tags: php, .htaccess

На данный момент редирект происходит так

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перенос сайта с http на https](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382888/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-http-%d0%bd%d0%b0-https)

Answer (score 2):

1 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

2 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

3 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

4 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

5 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.ru/$1 [L]
```

6 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} !=https
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

7 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

8 вариант

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Я использую MVC т.е по какой ссылке бы на сайте не перешел идет редирект на index.php и контроллер обрабатывает запросы и выводит страницу - из выше перечисленных вариантов сайт падает по причине большое кол-во запросов на страницу